# Adding new currencies in product lists page

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, currency, currency-rates

My client wants to display 3 different formats of currency which should be displayed on the product list page. Here is the screen shot for reference. 
[image: Currency]

Do you see that **$23.00** on right side? My client wants to display Euro and INR values to be displayed right under that USD value. How to do that. I took USD as default currency and INR and Euro as allowed currencies and imported standard conversion rates by using webserviceex. Please help me out.... I'm not understanding that where should I add the following line of codes...

```
$baseCode = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();      
    $allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies(); 
    $rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($baseCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));
    var_dump($rates);
```

Help me

Comment: the page looks like a `product_view` page and not `prdouct_list` page

Comment: @Serpyre: yeah, right. My client wanted me to get more expertise in magento... It was an experiment...

Comment: @Serpyre: yeah :) Can you try answering this question? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24039/modifying-back-end-so-that-we-can-use-3-default-price-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only simple products this should be easy.
Just add the following code in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml` right under `$this->getPriceHtml($_product)`.

```
<?php
//remember the current currency
$currentCurrency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
//remember the current currency object
$currentCurrencyObject = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency();
//get allowed currencies
$allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies();
foreach ($allowedCurrencies as $currency) {
    //skip the current currency
    if ($currency != $currentCurrency) {
        //load the currency object
        $currObject = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load($currency);
        //change the store currency
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrency($currObject);
        //show the price in the new currency
        echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '-'.$currency);
    }
}
//reset the store currency
Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currentCurrency);
Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrency($currentCurrencyObject);
?>
```

You may also need to add the same in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml` but change `echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-'.$currency);` to `echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-clone-'.$currency);`

If you have custom options involved or configurable or bundle products this may not work. Most probably you will need some custom javascript to make the prices change when you change the options.

**[EDIT]**
The answer above is for the product view page. But it should work for product list page also. Just add the same code after the price is shown. You can also optimize this so you won't have to load the currencies each time you show a product in the list.

Comment: Can't we do it from backed? Can we add 2 custom price fields under price tab and make them default to EURO and INR?

Comment: I think so. You can use `Mage::helper('core')->currency(YOUR VALUE HERE, true, false)` to print the values.

Comment: Will it work for multiple products?

Comment: Most probably. You can try it.

Comment: yeah, tried and it didn't work for rwd theme